# Field Level Security and Validation Rule

Tags: security

I have a validation rule on Field1, which uses Field2 in the rule, Now I applied FLS to field2 as hidden. Now when I try to access Field1 in my Visualforce page, I dont see the Field1.

I was wondering if there is anything between Validation Rule & Field Level Security?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Field Level Security and Validation Rules are separate. A validation rule should not effect field visibility at all.

I would check Field Level Security on your Field1 and verify it has the correct permissions.

Comment: Thank you for confirmation. Looks like something else might be going on. Its really confusing, I have a FieldSet I am using in a VF Component, and then using Dynamic VF Binding. I will post a separate question.